# Can you check that an exception is thrown with doctest in Python?

Tags: python, doctest

Is it possible to write a `doctest` unit test that will check that an exception is raised?
For example, if I have a function `foo(x)` that is supposed to raise an exception if `x < 0`, how would I write the `doctest` for that?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Yes. You can do it. The [doctest module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) and Wikipedia has an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctest#Example_2:_doctests_embedded_in_a_README.txt_file) of it.

```
   >>> x
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     ...
   NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Don't need the `...`

Answer (score 15):

```
>>> scope # doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'scope' is not defined
```

Don't know why the previous answers don't have the IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL. I need this for it to work. Py versioin: 3.7.3.

Comment: You can ignore the exception details by using the ellipsis `...` as in the other answers and the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#what-about-exceptions I see ellipsis as the more readable variant.

Comment: As of Python 3.9.7 (and probably earlier) you don't need `...` or `# doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL` for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log(-2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
ValueError: math domain error
```

ellipsis flag *# doctest: +ELLIPSIS* is not required to use ... in Traceback doctest

Comment: Are you saying we can omit the ellipsis? It's not clear that we can, or how to do it, based on the answer. If we can, could you edit your answer to make that clearer please? It would be pretty useful. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need ellipsis